# admin-ajax.php 403 forbidden only when calling from external file

Tags: functions, ajax

I am working on some AJAX pagination for my blog. I have everything working correctly when I put the Javascript at the bottom of index.php, but if I move it to my custom.js file that I am enqueuing in my `functions.php` I get 403 forbidden with the exact same Javascript.

Here's the working code from index.php:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.load-more', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('.posts').append(response);
            page++;
        });
    });
});
```

And here's the non-working code(403 forbidden) from my custom.js and functions.php I console logged the `theme.ajaxurl` variable and it is correctly outputting the URL to admin-ajax.php:

**custom.js**:

```
var page = 2;
$('body').on('click', '.load-more', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
        'page': page,
        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
    };

    $.post(theme.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $('.posts').append(response);
        page++;
    });
});
```

**functions.php**:

```
wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'theme', array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
));
```

Here's the AJAX callback from functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '9',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => -24
    );
    $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
```

Anyone know why this would work correctly when placing the javascript directly on the index.php file but not work when trying to call the javascript from a custom enqueued file in functions.php?

Comment: There's no code for your AJAX endpoint in your question, can you include it? Also have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? it's much easier to debug and a cleaner setup

Comment: @TomJNowell I have added the AJAX callback from my functions.php file. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with the REST API

Comment: Alright, I figured out the source of the issue. It has to do with the line `check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');`. If I comment that line out in functions.php, the ajax function works from the external JS file. I guess my next question is, is that security measure necessary? If so, any ideas why that would be causing a 403 error only when the JS is called from an external file?

Comment: since it's a read only frontend request, I'd remove it. Also keep in mind that the existing REST API endpoints provided with core can already do this out of the box